# Is it possible to use or function in index match vba?

Tags: excel, vba, match

I'm doing Excel uses macros for reporting purposes and this excel file will be used by a few different users. Users will upload reporting data from our ERP system and after that macros are used to combine data from different systems.

I'm trying to use index match in vba. For the match function I'm selecting column based on column header. The tricky part is that column headers can be either in English or in Finnish depending on what language user is using in ERP system.

I've already been able to construct a code that searches correct column and uses it in idex match function if there is only one search criteria for example English version. Can u guys help how to create a line that searches either finnish or english version for example "Order number" or "Tilausnumero"

```
Dim colm As Long
Dim colmLet As String
Dim colmOrder As Long
Dim colmOrdLet As String


colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Cost Center", Sheets("Orders").Rows(1), 0)
colmLet = Split(Cells(1, colm).Address, "$")(1)

colmOrder = WorksheetFunction.Match("Order No", Sheets("Orders").Rows(1), 0)
colmOrdLet = Split(Cells(1, colmOrder).Address, "$")(1)

Sheets("Postings").Select

Range("AH2").Formula = _
       "=INDEX(Orders!" & colmLet & ":" & colmLet & ",MATCH('Postings'!Y:Y,Orders!" & colmOrdLet & ":" & colmOrdLet & ",0))

End Sub
```

Comment: You can look into `.Evaluate` and parse a formula with variables to it instead of a whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in your code something like this and You will know which language was chosen :)

```
On Error Resume Next
colm = 0
colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Order No", Sheets("Orders").Rows(1), 0)
If colm = 0 Then
    colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Tilausnumero", Sheets("Orders").Rows(1), 0)
End If
If colm = 0 Then
    MsgBox "it's neither English nor Finnish"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```